# Why did Charlie keep walking?

Tags: glitch

The series *[Glitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glitch_(TV_series))* is billed as a paranormal television series despite having no clear cut paranormal instances in the entire first season, but that's something for another moan.  For the most part I'm fine with waiting for explanations in the second season, but one thing is sticking with me.

The below features heavy spoilers from the final episode, read at your own risk.

> Towards the end of the final episode of the season, we have Vic taking the remaining returnees, with the exception of Paddy, to the bridge to try and "return" them to where they belong.  Now, upon getting to the bridge he gets John to grab Kate and drag her while he drags out Charlie and Kirstie.  He then apparently convinces Charlie to keep walking on his own while he drags Kirstie at gun point.

Okay, this is all pretty standard and believable here, sort of.

> We will leave alone that the altruistic Charlie has more or less tried to protect Kirstie from everything all season.  Very out of character.

However, upon a certain event everything seems to change.

> Once Vic is dead, Kirstie manages to drag Charlie back from the bridge, and then they make no reference to the fact that he walked of his own accord for the rest of the episode.  Charlie even thanks Kirstie for saving him despite him doing it on his own.

So, is there any indication as to why Charlie did this and then seems to have had an immediate change of heart?

Comment: People coming back from the grave sounds paranormal enough to me, although there are hints of a science fictional explanation.

Answer (score 3):

When Charlie is guarding the wounded Vic, Vic talks to him.

Up to that point, we've seen Charlie trying to remember who he was and how he died, remembering his lover and how *he* died, already feeling guilty upon remembering that.
He's clearly impressionable, and Vic takes advantage of that.

> "(...) none of you are supposed to be here."
>   "(...)"
>    "Think of all your mates who died in that Great War. Died screaming for their mothers.
>   You remember your mates, don't you, Charlie?"
>   "(...)"
>   "And you remember someone who didn't make it back."
>   "(...)"
>   "When you think of him, doesn't it make you wonder why you're standing here now in front of me alive instead of him?"
>   "(...)"
>   "Then can't you see, Charlie, that your coming back is wrong? That it makes a total mockery of his death? Of his sacrifice? Oh, Charlie. I don't know how you can live with yourself."

Already doubting himself and his new (re-) existence, Charlie is under Vic's influence. Although Vic still needs to coerce him to come along, he doesn't need much to do it.
Once on the bridge, Charlie seems to feel that it's indeed for the best to cease existing and so he keeps walking.

Comment: @Naryna, is there anything I could add or edit to make this answer "acceptable"?